# LogicException: Unknown module in the requested list: 'Amazon_Core' in

Tags: magento2, exception

I am trying to install magento-2.3.2 in my windows 10 64 bit system.

First of all I clone from magento 2.3.2 repo.

`git clone https://github.com/magento/magento2.git`

and then I run `composer install` to install all listed modules inside `composer.json`.

When I try to install Magento-2.3.2, in the last step I am getting this error.

Installation is incomplete. 
Check the console log for errors before trying again.

> [ERROR] LogicException: Unknown module in the requested list:
>   'Amazon_Core' in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php:468
>   Stack trace: #0
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(427):
>   Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->readListOfModules(Array, Array,
>   'enable-modules') #1
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(357):
>   Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->createModulesConfig(Array, true) #2
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(109):

Now, what's wrong with the **`amazon_core module`** that one can resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Github repo is the develop version if you plan to make pull requests. Download magento via the downloads section on their website. The install will go a lot smoother.